# Is there a formula for $\mathbb{E}\left[X \mid a \leq X \leq b\right]$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose $X$ is a random variable which has nonnegative support and $0 \leq a \leq b$. Is there a formula for 
$$\mathbb{E}\left[X \mid a \leq X \leq b\right]\text{?}$$
Specifically, this came up in an actuarial exam problem I was doing. Let $X$ be uniformly distributed over the interval $[0, \theta]$. What is $\mathbb{E}\left[X \mid 100 \leq X \leq 1000\right]$? I thought about perhaps using double expectation (more like "triple" in this case) to come up with a formula:
$$\mathbb{E}\left[100 \leq X \leq 1000\right] = \dfrac{\mathbb{E}\left[X\right] - \mathbb{E}\left[X \mid X \leq 100\right]\mathbb{P}\left(X \leq 100\right) - \mathbb{E}\left[X\mid X > 1000\right]\mathbb{P}\left(X > 1000\right)}{\mathbb{P}\left(100 \leq X \leq 1000\right)}$$
but it isn't clear to me how to find the conditional expectations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are measure-theoretic definitions of all these things, and for instance, $\mathbb{P}(A | B)$ can be defined as $\mathbb{E}[1_A | B]$. In your case,
\begin{gather*}
\mathbb{E}[X | A] \dot = \frac{\mathbb{E}[X 1_A]}{\mathbb{P}(A)} \equiv \frac{1}{\mathbb{P}(A)}\int_A X d\mathbb{P}.
\end{gather*}

(See, e.g., Khoshnevisan's *Probability*, p. 124)

Comment: So in the (absolutely) continuous and nonnegative case, for example, $\mathbb{E}\left[X \mid X \leq 100\right] = \dfrac{1}{\mathbb{P}\left(X \leq 100\right)}\int\limits_{0}^{100}x f_{X}(x)\text{ d}x$?

Comment: Looks right to me.